# How to automatically flag an entity when the form is submitted?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I created a small custom module in Drupal 8 to moderate new entities and update entities.

The module is simple. It marks with the help of the flag module, the entities created or updated automatically.

Here is my module :

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Holds hook implementation for the Admin Task Notify module.
 */

use Drupal\flag\FlaggingInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\commerce_store\Entity\Store;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\group\Entity\Group;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\comment\Entity\Comment;

/**
 * Implements hook_user_insert() and hook_user_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'admin_task_notify_flag_user';
  }
}
 
function admin_task_notify_flag_user(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $flag_id = 'moderate_user';
  $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
  $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
  $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
  $user_to_flag_uid = $form_state->getValue('uid');
  $user_to_flag = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($user_to_flag_uid);
  $is_admin = $user_to_flag->hasRole('administrator');
  $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $user_to_flag, $user_admin);
  if (!$flag_status && !$is_admin) {
    $flag_service->flag($flag, $user_to_flag, $user_admin);
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_store_insert() and hook_store_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_commerce_store_insert(Store $commerce_store) {
  if ($commerce_store->bundle() == 'ephemere' || $commerce_store->bundle() == 'personnel' || $commerce_store->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_store';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_commerce_store_update(Store $commerce_store) {
  if ($commerce_store->bundle() == 'ephemere' || $commerce_store->bundle() == 'personnel' || $commerce_store->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_store';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_product_insert() and hook_product_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_commerce_product_insert(Product $commerce_product) {
  if ($commerce_product->bundle() == 'produit' || $commerce_product->bundle() == 'service') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_product';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $commerce_product, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_product, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_commerce_product_update(Product $commerce_product) {
  if ($commerce_product->bundle() == 'produit' || $commerce_product->bundle() == 'service') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_product';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $commerce_product, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_product, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_group_insert() and hook_group_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_group_insert(Group $group) {
  if ($group->bundle() == 'personnel' || $group->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_group';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $group, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $group, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_group_update(Group $group) {
  if ($group->bundle() == 'personnel' || $group->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_group';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $group, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $group, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert() and hook_node_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_node_insert(Node $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'annonce' || $node->bundle() == 'article' || $node->bundle() == 'demande' || $node->bundle() == 'discussion' || $node->bundle() == 'evenement' || $node->bundle() == 'itineraire' || $node->bundle() == 'recipe') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_node';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $node, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $node, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_node_update(Node $node) {
  if ($node->bundle() == 'annonce' || $node->bundle() == 'article' || $node->bundle() == 'demande' || $node->bundle() == 'discussion' || $node->bundle() == 'evenement' || $node->bundle() == 'itineraire' || $node->bundle() == 'recipe') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_node';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $node, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $node, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_comment_insert() and hook_comment_update().
 */
function admin_task_notify_comment_insert(Comment $comment) {
  if ($comment->bundle() == 'annonce' || $comment->bundle() == 'article' || $comment->bundle() == 'demande' || $comment->bundle() == 'discussion' || $comment->bundle() == 'evenement' || $comment->bundle() == 'itineraire' || $comment->bundle() == 'recipe' || $comment->bundle() == 'produit' || $comment->bundle() == 'service') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_comment';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $comment, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $comment, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}

function admin_task_notify_comment_update(Comment $comment) {
  if ($comment->bundle() == 'annonce' || $comment->bundle() == 'article' || $comment->bundle() == 'demande' || $comment->bundle() == 'discussion' || $comment->bundle() == 'evenement' || $comment->bundle() == 'itineraire' || $comment->bundle() == 'recipe' || $comment->bundle() == 'produit' || $comment->bundle() == 'service') {
    $flag_id = 'moderate_comment';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $comment, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $comment, $user_admin);
    }
  }
}
```

**This is what i'm looking to do :**

I want to automatically mark the store with the `payment_gateways` flag when the `commerce_store_payment_gateways_form` form is submitted.

I want to automatically flag the store with the `shipping_methods` flag when the `commerce_store_shipping_methods_form` form is submitted.

How can I do this ? What code should I add to my module ?

I started some code, but I don't know if it is correct and where to integrate it in my module.

I don't know if there is another way to do it.

```
  /**
   * Payment Gateways.
   */
  if ($commerce_store->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    if ($form_id == 'commerce_store_payment_gateways_form') {
      $flag_id = 'payment_gateways';
      $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
      $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
      $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
      $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
      if (!$flag_status) {
        $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
      }
    }
  }
  /**
   * Shipping Methods.
   */
  if ($commerce_store->bundle() == 'professionnel') {
    if ($form_id == 'commerce_store_shipping_methods_form') {
      $flag_id = 'shipping_methods';
      $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
      $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
      $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
      $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
      if (!$flag_status) {
        $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` to add custom submit handler to your forms:

```php
/* 
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
 */
function hook_form_commerce_store_payment_gateways_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
    if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
      $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit_handler';
    }
  }
}
```

Then put your flagging logic into the custom handler:

```php
function custom_form_submit_handler($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $flag_id = 'payment_gateways';
    $flag_service = \Drupal::service('flag');
    $flag = $flag_service->getFlagById($flag_id);
    $user_admin = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(1);
    $flag_status = $flag_service->getFlagging($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
    if (!$flag_status) {
      $flag_service->flag($flag, $commerce_store, $user_admin);
    }
}
```

Do the same for form `commerce_store_shipping_methods_form`.